# Is the a way to condense this into a FOR function, each button obviously has to match the number output

Tags: python, python-3.x

> K_1 is hitting the 1 key on the keyboard, I don't know if it is possible to put a variable into the actual pygame.K_ parameter. if I could figure out a way to add a variable to this I could condense my code down a lot because I am using this type of repetition on multiple occasions.
> I am making sudoku for anyone who is wondering

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_1]:
        numList[cell_num] = "1"
    if keys[pygame.K_2]:
        numList[cell_num] = "2"
    if keys[pygame.K_3]:
        numList[cell_num] = "3"
    if keys[pygame.K_4]:
        numList[cell_num] = "4"
    if keys[pygame.K_5]:
        numList[cell_num] = "5"
    if keys[pygame.K_6]:
        numList[cell_num] = "6"
    if keys[pygame.K_7]:
        numList[cell_num] = "7"
    if keys[pygame.K_8]:
        numList[cell_num] = "8"
    if keys[pygame.K_9]:
        numList[cell_num] = "9"
```

Comment: How should you handle multiple key presses, if `1` and `2` are pressed at the same time, what should `numList[cell_num]` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer event handling rather than looking at which keys are currently pressed. Presumably you're using a recent version of PyGame, so you should be able to handle `TEXTINPUT` [events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Here's a minimal example that just displays the key pressed, with a comment of where you'd set `numList[cell_num]`:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
# grab the first installed font
sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_fonts()[0], 80)
text = sys_font.render(" ", True, pygame.Color("turquoise")) # initially blank
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
width, height = 320, 240
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Text Input")
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.TEXTINPUT:
            if event.text in "123456789":
                text = sys_font.render(event.text, True, pygame.Color("turquoise"))
                # numList[cell_num] = event.text
    # Graphics
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
    # Draw Text in the center
    screen.blit(text, text.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center))
    # Update Screen
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

[image: Number 9]

Comment: This really helped, it works perfectly, for anyone needing the answer really fast, just append 
`elif event.type == pygame.TEXTINPUT:
            if event.text in "123456789":
                 numList[cell_num] = event.text`
to the end of your pygame.QUIT if statment

Answer (score 3):

To help reduce repetition I would use a `for each` statement. Additonally I would create a dictionary with a `key` and `value` to store all your values.

To avoid confusion I have renamed your `keys` variable as follows (we will be using a `key` later for so want to avoid confusion):

```
key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Then create a dictionary to hold all the pygame.K_parameters as the `key` and set the `value` to the number you want. This would look as follows:

```
 thisdict = {
  pygame.K_1: "1",
  pygame.K_2: "2",
  pygame.K_3: "3"
  #...etc...
}
```

After this, we can write a `for each` statement with an `if` statement. This would iterate through the dictionary each time the key was pressed and compare the `key_pressed` to the `key` in the dictionary. If the values equal each other than set `numList[cell_num]` to `value`:

```
for key, value in thisdict.items()
    if key_pressed == key :
        numList[cell_num] = value
    # you could use else if key_pressed is a key that isn't the ones you specifically want
```

There are probably a number of ways of doing this but this is how I would do it :)